# OSX – MAMP not showing latest Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, macos, mamp

OS X 10.11.1 ElCapitan
MAMP 3.4

Hi,

I have been working on a Wordpress website in MAMP, and it has all been working fine.

However, I made an error within Wordpress and decided to go back to an earlier backup of MAMP using 'Time Machine'. (My 'Time Machine' software is set to backup everything every hour.)

Now, when I launch MAMP, it only shows the website as it was about 4 or 5 days ago. It is the same across various Browsers. Even new images I had uploaded aren't showing in my Media folder – but I can see the images in my WordPress installation (wp-content/uploads/2015/11)

It almost seems like a cache issue, but I'm only guessing. Anyone have any ideas how I can get back to my current website?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your database was rolled back, but your WP content remained the same, and they're now out of sync.

Comment: Thanks for your info. That makes sense. The worst bit is that I didn't have a separate backup of the database. Do you know if there is any way I can find/get back to the previous database version? I have used MAMP this way before (via a backup of the whole MAMP folder) and they have always worked OK. I don't know why it's not working this time around.